# Excel VBA to get Word table data

Tags: excel, ms-word, ms-office, vba

[image: ScreenShot of Problem]

I found VBA code and modified it but it didn't work.

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename()
j = 1

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
For i = 1 To .Tables.Count
With .Tables(i)
'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
For iRow = 2 To .Rows.Count
For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
Cells(j, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
Next iCol
j = j + 1
Next iRow
End With
Next i 'Next Table

End With 'End of the document

Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have a Word document, with 750 pages, with a table on each page. I want to import the contents of the tables into an Excel file (with the exception of the first line of each table as that is the column names).

It throws an error (As shown in picture) -- Automation Error -- "Run-time Error 2147418105 (80010007)".

Comment: "hanged and gave some popup" is not really useful in diagnosing a problem: it would help to provide specific error messages in your question. What did the popup say?

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. Just noticed that the screenshot wasn't visible enough. Here's the error anyway

"Run-time Error 2147418105 (80010007)
Automation Error

Comment: I don't have a Mac to test on, but that code looks OK to me...

Comment: As Tim said, the code looks good.  Another issue (as seen in the screen-shot) may be that 750 tables is causing Word to crash.  Is there any way to get the tables out of Word first?

Comment: I had the same suspicions. Unfortunately I don't have any way to get the tables out of word...! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot it appears you got through row 10 and started row 11 before the error occurred. Without seeing the full document or knowing the table schema I would try one or more of the following approaches:

1. Try setting breakpoint before word crashes, then step through to see if specific data or some other issue may be the culprit.  (At the Row loop (`For iRow = 2 To .Rows.Count`) or add `IF iRow=10 THEN debug.break` then step into each line (Debug>Step Into (F8)) from there.).
2. If table ends near 10 rows then try closing wdDoc (`Set wdDoc = Nothing`), reopen, and continue import starting right where you left off. This sounds impractical, but if it works around the bug then you can try adjusting some values and narrowing down the root cause.
3. Run this VBA on a computer that has lots of free RAM. MS Word may be loading entire 750-page document into memory, then hitting OutOfMemory, pagefile thrashing, or other OS resource limit that devolves into app crash.
4. Try splitting the 750-page document into 8 files with no more than 100 pages per file. Then loop through each. If that works then look into computer resource limits or issue with Word size limitations.

FYI: I've seen some issues with Word stability at ~1000 pages but I had lots of screenshots and other formatting goodies in that example (and I found solution that kept it split into 27 separate reference detail-level sections with an overall <50-page top-level document loosely referring to them.)

A Year late and short of a known fix, but this debugging checklist might help you or others who stumble upon this thread :-). I'm working with very similar routine (and just started searching for how to pull statistics for each table :-)).  Cheers and good luck!